# Have verbatim code as an equation

Tags: equations, environments, verbatim, nesting

I have a little snippet of program code / input that needs to be rendered with the exact layout as typed in (verbatim). Is it possible to have this as an equation? I tried to nest the `Verbatim` environment in an `equation` without success. Any help?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{Verbatim}
... hack hack hack ...
\end{Verbatim}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Why do you need it in an equation? Do you just want to have it numbered? How many lines of "code" do you have in the `equation`?

Comment: @Werner Yeah. I want to have it numbered, centered and formatted just like an equation. There are about seven lines of code.

Comment: Are the seven lines of code in the same equation, or in separate equations?

Comment: @Werner they should all go in one equation.

Answer (score 12):

If you're only after typesetting a single equation that has some verbatim text in it, you could use the short form of `verbatim`, as in `\verb!...!`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \verb!f(x)=ax^2+bx+c! \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
In order to typeset $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, see~\eqref{eq:1}.
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\eqref{<lab>}` that puts brackets `( )` around the equation reference. And, of course, these `equation` environments can be intermixed with the text as needed.

The above is a quick-and-easy way of typesetting `verbatim` in an equation. If you want multiple `verbatim` content in an aligned equation environment (like [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align`), you could use the [`fancyvrb` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) to capture your verbatim content and then use it in the `align` environment. Using `verbatim` directly in `align` does not work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb
\begin{document}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\SaveVerb{VerbA}|f(x)=ax^2+bx+c|% First equation verbatim
\SaveVerb{VerbB}|g(x)=dx^2+ex+f|% Second equation verbatim
\begin{align}
  \UseVerb{VerbA} \label{eq:1} \\
  \UseVerb{VerbB} \label{eq:2}
\end{align}
In order to typeset $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, see~\eqref{eq:1}. There is also~\eqref{eq:2} that shows you how to typeset $g(x)=dx^2+ex+f$.
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**: Grouping these into a single "equation" is similar to the original `equation` environment, and merely using an `array` environment for "collection" of the content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left.\begin{array}{r@{}l}
    \verb!f(x)!&\verb!=ax^2+bx+c! \\
    \verb!g(x)+2f(x)!&\verb!=y!
  \end{array}\right\} \label{eq:input}
\end{equation}
One could use~\eqref{eq:input} as input.
\end{document}
```

Although not entirely necessary, the above example uses a zero-width column separation `@{}` to align the equal signs `=` of the `\verb` equation parts.

Comment: Yeah... that looks better, though I want to have all those lines as *one* equation. (See them as an ascii-art representation of a matrix that serves as an input to another program and thus mustn't be typeset differently)

Comment: @FUZxxl: Using an `array` you could just combine the separate equations with a single equation number. If that's what you're after, see my answer edit. Or are you after something else?

Answer (score 5):

a multi-lined equation with a single equation number can be obtained by using one of the "subsidiary" environments from `amsmath`.  each line needs to have `\verb` applied individually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  &\verb|f(x)=ax^2=bx+c|\\
  &\verb|g(x)=dx^2=ex+f|\\
  &\verb|h(x)=kx^2=mx+n|
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\newenvironment{texteq}{%
    \begin{equation}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}%
}{%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{equation}%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}
```

You will still have to start a verbatim environment inside your texteq environment:

```
\begin{texteq}
    \begin{verbatim}
    ...
    \end{verbatim}
\end{texteq}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question and I would like to add a simple answer, since for me just using `\mathtt{}` was enough.

```
 \begin{equation}
 \mathtt{Test} = x + y
 \end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fancyvrb` and its `BVerbatim` environment. In order to center the equation number, use `gathered` (but add `\normalbaselines` because `gathered` will increase the interline space).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{EqVerbatim}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{gathered}\normalbaselines\begin{BVerbatim}}
 {\end{BVerbatim}\end{gathered}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{EqVerbatim}
| 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 |
\end{EqVerbatim}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]